# jQuery - next(element) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this structure:

```
<ul>
  <li> 
    <a> link .. </a>
    <span> text </span>
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
```

I'm adding a click event on both the `<span>` and `<a>` elements and I'm trying to select the nested `<ul>` using `$(this).next("ul");`

It works for the span, but not for the link. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A click handler on the anchor will not see the UL if you're using `next` to grab it, since `next` will only select the *very next* sibling. You can try:

```
$("a").nextAll("ul").hide();
```

or:

```
$("a").parent().find("ul").hide();
```

or:

```
$("a").siblings("ul").hide();
```

Comment: nextAll() works for me, thank you. But it's weird that next() is accepting arguments, if it returns the very next element anyway.

Comment: @Alex - the argument it accepts means 'return the *very next* element *only if* it matches the passed selector. It is extremely unintuitive, and this question has popped up hundreds of times in various incarnations for the very same reason.

Comment: That explains why my code didn't work the other day :-P. One question thou, the nextAll returns several elements, right (all the next ones that are a match, right)? Will then nextAll('ul:first') return the element you're searching for?

Comment: @Alexandr - Yes. I did, however, assume that there was just one UL on the same level (based on the markup in the question) so I omitted the `:first` pseudo-selector. (I did think about including it though :)